I am Using Kafka streams in my ongoing springboot project , i would like to extract the timestamp from input topic , hw to do it?
Everytime the kafka streams subscribes to input topic and dumps the data to output topic , now i would like to the method to extract the timestamp and dump into the json object that object will be sent to output topic
i have tried using kafka consumers inbuild method that is using .timestamp , its not working in kafka stream .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In Kafka Streams, you can use the Processor API to access the timestamp, eg, buidler.stream(...).process(...).to(...)'
In newer version, the Processor#process(Record) method gives you direct access via Record#timestamp().
In older version, you would need to use the provided ProcessorContext#timestamp() method, that you get via Processor#init(ProcessorContext)
